# JavaFX BorderPane inside an AnchorPane?

Tags: java, javafx, window, borderpane

I'm currently trying to show a `BorderPane` inside my `AnchorPane` (that is also inside my `StackPane`). I tried to show a new Scene but it show me 2 items in my Windows taskbar, and this is not really what I want.

For exemple, when you open the Preference in Eclipse, u get another window that is not visible in the taskbar.

So basically, the only thing I need is a window that looks like an ImageView, like anchored in the `AnchorPane` , not resizable and undecorated.

[Expected result at end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5qrr.png)

This is what I tried:

```
btnDice.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Scene newScene = new Scene(new BorderPane(), 230, 100);
                Stage newWindow = new Stage();
                newWindow.setScene(newScene);

                newWindow.show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: So... are we suposed to do it for you ? Where is you code, with what you've tried, because i don't see it.

Comment: Not at all, just asking for a good method to do it. Should I create a new Scene and set some parameters? Or should I use something else? I think you don't really need the code, just need advices

Comment: Hold on, I'm legit first time on SO, just trying to add some code

Comment: You might be in the wrong place then, SO is more of a "mutual debugging and dev helping" Q&A site i would say, anyway if you are only seeking for advice better precise it, could be an interesting question, but as it is right now peoples will tend to have the same reaction as me, be it good or bad :p.

Comment: I edited it. Do you have any solution to make it  anchored, typically like an inventory that you open in a game. It doesn't create another application in the taskbar, and it looks anchored.

Comment: Couldn't you just play with relative positions ? By using the window's size and you pane size, i'am unsure since i've never done this before and this is clearly not more than a trick, but i believe there is a way to do it.

Comment: Yeah. I'm tempted to just set my stage like `newWindow.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);`. But i'm pretty sure that there is a better way to do it

Comment: Just add the pane as a child. There could be problems but we'd need to make guesses about them... Depending on your needs a stage with the parent stage as owner and with modality set to `WINDOW_MODAL` could also work...

Comment: Gonna try this @fabian :)

Comment: Well @fabian it was exactly what I needed! Thanks!